# Error: PlatformException(no_fragment_activity, local_auth plugin requires activity to be a FragmentActivity., null)

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Getting this error while using local_auth version 0.6.0
It's working fine for iOS but getting this error in android.
Already have implemented `class MainActivity: FlutterFragmentActivity()` but still getting this issue

Comment: Add some code man!!!

Comment: Refer to this comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33429#issuecomment-496598997

Answer (score 41):

This is what I did to solve this issue.

Change your `MainActivity.kt` as below:

```
package com.[your.package]

import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

class MainActivity: FlutterFragmentActivity() {
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine)
    }
}
```

However, after changing this `MainActivity.kt`, I also faced some other issue with the `Theme.AppCompat`. Check this out https://gist.github.com/akifarhan/f70a2c777651f2ea61a15eb92a5939c1 for the solution.

Comment: I have same issue "You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity". Simple change "android:theme" to this line below in activity tag in android manifest, work for me: 
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light".

Comment: For me at first this and other many answers kept ending in the same error, but then I stopped the app run, and in the terminal executed **flutter clean** and it worked like a charm in the next build!

Answer (score 12):

From the docs -https://pub.dev/documentation/local_auth/latest/

Simply use the code below in your MainActivity.kt

```
 package [package ID here]

    import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity
    
    class MainActivity: FlutterFragmentActivity() {
    }
```

Uninstall your current build of the app and then rebuild again

By the way, ensure you're not making multiple calls for

```
 auth.authenticate(...)
```

Comment: Than You, I needed to uninstall and rebuild the app to make it pick up the changes!

Comment: This is the correct answer. For those using 3.2.5 or later I've noticed that starting your project on a MacOS gives your different results in your MainActivity.kt file, than if you start the project on a Windows 11 machine. Windows 11 creates the file and uses FlutterFragmentActivity, MacOS project start creates the file and uses FlutterActivity. FYI!

Answer (score 4):

change your main activity to override FlutterFragmentActivity

```
import android.os.Bundle
import io.flutter.app.FlutterFragmentActivity
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

class MainActivity: FlutterFragmentActivity() {
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
      GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this)
  }
}
```

if you are using flutter embedding version 2

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

class MainActivity: FlutterFragmentActivity() {
   override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: 
     FlutterEngine) {
     GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Flutter details

Flutter version 1.22.4 at /Users/macbookpro/Desktop/development/flutter

- Framework revision 1aafb3a8b9 (4 weeks ago), 2020-11-13 09:59:28 -0800
- Engine revision 2c956a31c0
- Dart version 2.10.4
- local_auth: ^0.6.3+4

If you are using java then change your main activity to this

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
public class MainActivity extends FlutterFragmentActivity{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using local_auth 0.6.2+3

My MainActivity.kt

```
 package xx.xx.xxx
 import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
 import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity
 import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
 import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

class MainActivity: FlutterFragmentActivity() {
  override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
   }
}
```

I was using SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame meta tag, Removing it from my main/AndroidManifest.xml works absolutely fine now.

```
<meta-data
android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
android:value="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

In  my case, i forgot to change in AndroidManifest.xml file.
Complete changes for reference

MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import io.flutter.app.FlutterFragmentActivity;
import io.flutter.plugins.flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle.FlutterAndroidLifecyclePlugin;
import io.flutter.plugins.localauth.LocalAuthPlugin;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterFragmentActivity  {
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FlutterAndroidLifecyclePlugin.registerWith(
                registrarFor(
                        "io.flutter.plugins.flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle.FlutterAndroidLifecyclePlugin"));
        LocalAuthPlugin.registerWith(registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.localauth.LocalAuthPlugin"));
    }
}
```

Then

AndroidManifest.xml

From

```
  <application
        android:label="<name>"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
           android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity"
           ....
```

To

```
  <application
        android:label="<name>"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
           android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity"
           ....
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried adding the code in MainActivity.kt. For some reason, it doesn't take the code from MainActivity.kt and only searches for MainActivity.java. So the following code in MainActivity.java fixed the issue for me.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.<package_name>;

import android.os.Bundle;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
import io.flutter.plugins.flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle.FlutterAndroidLifecyclePlugin;
import io.flutter.plugins.localauth.LocalAuthPlugin;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterFragmentActivity {

    public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) 
    {
      GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using ***Flutter 3.3.5***, ***Dart: 2.18.2*** versions

Made no change in *MainActivity.kt* as such, also made no change in *style.xml* file.

Just added below code in
**AndroidManifest.xml** inside the activity tag

```
<activity  android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity" </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

2nd answer worked fine if we remove **@NotNull** like

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

class MainActivity: FlutterFragmentActivity() {
   override fun configureFlutterEngine( flutterEngine: 
     FlutterEngine) {
     GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to the dependencies in your app level `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies{
    api "androidx.core:core:1.1.0-aplha03"
}
```